Analysis of the relative likelihood with parametric bootstrapping
Using parametric bootstrapping, I find that the relative likelihood of model A is $l_A$ and of model B is $l_B$. Repeating the analysis several times yields a distribution of likelihood values for each model.
To evaluate which model performs better, I assume that the best estimation of the likelihood of model A ($\mu_A$) is the mean likelihood with a variance ($\sigma^2_A$) given by the sample variance divided by the number of tests. Is this approach correct? Can I then say that model A is significantly better than model B based on these values?
